# Встречалось ли число раньше c++

Tags: c++

Комплилятор яндекса выдаёт ошибку превышения вывода, я так понимаю это связано с переносом строки после последнего вывода, как это можно решить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int k;
   multiset<int>s;
    while(true){

        cin >> k;
        cout << (s.find(k) != s.end() ? "YES\n" : "NO\n");
        if(s.find(k) == s.end()){
             s.insert(k);
        }
    if(cin.get() =='\n')
            break;

    }




}
```

Comment: Можно символ новой строки печатать только после проверки считанного символа на равенство `\n`. Т.е. сперва `cout << (s.find(k) != s.end() ? "YES" : "NO");`, а затем в конце цикла `cout << "\n";`. Но гарантируется ли, что входная последовательность чисел завершается символом новой строки? Если нет, то получим бесконечный цикл. Попробуйте так: `std::set<int> s;` `for (int val; std::cin >> val; )` `std::cout << (s.insert(val).second ? "NO\n" : "YES\n");`.

Answer (score 1):

Подвинуть `cin >> k` в условие цикла:

```
while (std::cin >> k) {...}
```

При таком подходе читается не одна строка, а любое их количество, пока числа не кончатся.